# Chaining apt commands

Tags: apt

I've noticed that the majority of Ubuntu help websites present apt commands in the following format:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:[ppa-address]
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install [application-name]
```

But I know that apt commands like this one work too:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:[ppa-address] && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install [application-name]
```

Is there a particular reason that most sites present in the first format? Are there known issues with chaining commands with &&, or to put it another way are there any benefits/drawbacks to using either method?

Further, other then loss of internet, are there any circumstances in which an apt command might fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I think sites list them one by one just for clarity. It's easier to run one at a time and understand what it does then it is to run, say 3, all at once.

I might point out too, not all sites *do* list commands one by one. For example, in the [OMG Ubuntu article on installing Unity Tweak Tool](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool) the commands are listed as:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

It's also worth noting that `&&` will *only* run the second or third (etc) command if the command before it returns exit status `0`. In other words, the command after `&&`  will only be run if the command *before* `&&` completes successfully.

If you'd like your string of commands to execute one by one *no matter if any fail* you would separate each command with `;` instead of `&&`. For example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:[ppa-address] ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install [application-name]
```

(Of course, this wouldn't be a good thing to do when installing packages!)

There are a number of reasons why an `apt` command would fail:

- `apt-get install` could fail for quite a few reasons, among them dependency issues, not enough disk space, no internet connection, or an old or malformed `sources.list` file.
- `apt-get update` could fail for similar reasons, a malformed `sources.list`, no internet connection, a 404 PPA, etc.

These are just some of the things that would cause `apt` to fail, causing commands after `&&` to not be run.

Answer (score 1):

It's presented in the first form because it's easier to read.

Plus, if you need to review your history for *one* of the commands, it's easier than picking one part of a long, complex command.

Comment: Another reason: it is easier to edit if you made a mistake.